# Excel file format converter

Tags: c#, performance, excel

I'm using C# .NET Core 2.1 and Excel lib `DotnetCore.NPOI`

I'm converting `xls` file to `xlsx` by loading `xls` and copying sheet by sheet, cell by cell to `xlsx` - How can I improve performance / ram usage here?

```
private string ConvertToXSLX(string path) 
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var result = XLS_to_XLSX_Converter.Convert(fs);

        // (file.xls) + x = file.xlsx
        path = $"{path}x";

        using (var fs2 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs2.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

---

```
public static byte[] Convert(Stream sourceStream)
{
    var source = new HSSFWorkbook(sourceStream);
    var destination = new XSSFWorkbook();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.NumberOfSheets; i++)
    {
        var hssfSheet = (HSSFSheet)source.GetSheetAt(i);

        var xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet)destination.CreateSheet(source.GetSheetAt(i).SheetName);

        CopyRows(hssfSheet, xssfSheet);
    }

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        destination.Write(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

private static void CopyRows(HSSFSheet hssfSheet, XSSFSheet destination)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hssfSheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows; i++)
    {
        destination.CreateRow(i);

        var cells = hssfSheet.GetRow(i)?.Cells ?? new List<ICell>();

        for (int j = 0; j < cells.Count; j++)
        {
            var row = destination.GetRow(i);
            row.CreateCell(j);

            CopyCell((HSSFCell)cells[j], (XSSFCell)row.Cells[j]);
        }   
    }
}

private static void CopyCell(HSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell)
{
    CopyCellValue(oldCell, newCell);
}

private static void CopyCellValue(HSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell)
{
    switch (oldCell.CellType)
    {
        case CellType.String:
            newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.StringCellValue);
            break;
        case CellType.Numeric:
            newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.NumericCellValue);
            break;
        case CellType.Blank:
            newCell.SetCellType(CellType.Blank);
            break;
        case CellType.Boolean:
            newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.BooleanCellValue);
            break;
        case CellType.Error:
            newCell.SetCellErrorValue(oldCell.ErrorCellValue);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing to a `MemoryStream` only to get a `byte[]` to write to another stream, you can definitely avoid this intermediate conversion:

```
private string ConvertToXSLX(string inputPath) 
{
    string outputPath = Path.ChangeExtension(inputPath, ".xlsx");

    using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputPath))
    using (var output = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        XLS_to_XLSX_Converter.Convert(input, output);
    }

    return outputPath;
}
```

The change in `Convert()` should be trivial.

Also note that I'm using `Path.ChangeExtension()` instead of manually adding a character, code is clear without any comment and it handles *special* cases for you (for example a trailing space).

---

In `CopyRows()` you create an empty `List<ICell>`, you do not need to and you can avoid the initial allocation simply using `Enumerable.Empty<ICell>()` (and changing your code to work with an enumeration) or - at least - reusing the same empty object (move it outside the loop and create it with an initial capacity of 0).

---

In `CopyCellValue()` you have an empty `default` case for your `switch`. It's a good thing to always have `default` but it has a purpose: detect *unknown* cases. If you put a `break` then you're silently ignoring them. Is it on purpose? Write a comment to explain you ignore unknown cells. It's an error? Throw an exception.

---

I never used DotnetCore.NPOI then I can't comment about the way you use it, be sure to dispose all the intermediate `IDisposable` objects.